# Reference server URL in Location response header

Tags: swagger, documentation, openapi, redoc

In the server object I defined an URL:

```
servers: 
 - url: https://localhost:8088/abc
```

and in the response definition I want to reference this server URL:

```
/test-sub-url:
  post:
    requestBody:
      required: true
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              id: 
               description: Some ID
               type: string
    responses:
      '201':
        description: Created
        headers:
          Location:
            required: true
            schema:
              type: string
              format: url
              example: $reference server URL here$
```

Is it possible to reference the server URL from the example of the Location response header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `example` keyword requires a literal example value, so no, you can't reference another keyword there.